# How do I make the CKEditor Markdown extension output GitHub Flavored Markdown?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, markdown, ckeditor5, github-flavored-markdown

I am using CKEditor 5 build I made from their Online Builder. I have included the Markdown extension and it works - it outputs Markdown. But when I add a table, it outputs it as HTML. How do I set it to use GFM (as shown [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/markdown.html))?

Comment: please show your input including the table and the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what the problem was: I didn't set the first table row as table header. When I did that, the editor now outputs only markdown.